# Laravel 4 Auth fails

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have tried this Laravel Auth but it returns 'no' everytime.

```
$logging_user = array(
    'user_name' => 'abcde',
    'user_password'=> Hash::make('11111')
);

if (Auth::attempt($logging_user)) {
     return 'yes';
}
else {
     return 'no';
}
```

My table structure is like this

```
users {
    id,
    user_name,
    user_password,
    user_email
}
```

My model User.php has already implemented UserInterface

```
//inherited
public function getAuthIdentifier() {
    return $this->getKey();
}

//inherited
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->user_password;
}

//inherited
public function getReminderEmail() {
    return $this->user_email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally fixed it by changing

```
$logging_user = array(
    'user_name' => 'abcde',
    'user_password'=> Hash::make('11111')
);
```

to

```
$logging_user = array(
    'user_name' => 'abcde',
    'password'=> Hash::make('11111')
);
```